# MSBuild error in Universal Windows app project

Tags: c#, xaml, msbuild, windows-10-universal

I'm currently having an issue with building a Universal Windows app using Visual Studio 2015. Whenever I try to compile my project I get the following error:

```
Child node "2" exited prematurely. Shutting down. Diagnostic information may be found in files in the temporary files directory named MSBuild_*.failure.txt.
```

This error occurs whenever there are XAML files present in the application. It does not matter what the files contain. A single empty XAML file with it's build action set to `Page` or `ApplicationDefinition` is enough to make this error appear.

Looking further into the diagnostic logs it seems the error occurs at the `CompileXaml` task with the following exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
   at Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Build.Tasks.NativeMethods.WriteWithCheckSum(IStream[] xamlStreams, Int32 numFiles, String[] pbChecksum, Int32 checksumSize, IXbfMetadataProvider provider, TargetOSVersion targetVersion, UInt32 xbfGenerationFlags, IStream[] xbfStreams, Int32& errorCode, Int32& errorFileIndex, Int32& errorLine, Int32& errorColumn)
   at Microsoft.Xaml.XBF.XbfGenerator.GenerateXbfFromStreams(IStream[] inputStreams, IStream[] outputStreams, UInt32 xbfGenerationFlags, String[] checksums, TargetOSVersion targetOS, Int32& errorCode, Int32& errorFile, Int32& errorLine, Int32& errorPosition)
   at Microsoft.Xaml.XBF.XbfGenerator.GenerateAll(String targetPlatformVersion, UInt32 xbfGenerationFlags)
   at Microsoft.Xaml.XBF.XbfGenerator.GenerateXbfFiles(String targetPlatformVersion, UInt32 xbfGenerationFlags, Boolean v80Compat)
   at Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Build.Tasks.CompileXamlInternal.GenerateXbfFiles(List`1 xamlList)
   at Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Build.Tasks.CompileXamlInternal.DoExecute()
   at Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Build.Tasks.CompileXaml.Execute()
```

What could be the cause of this exception?

Troubleshooting steps already taken but to no avail:

- Restarting PC
- Reinstalling Visual Studio and the .NET framework
- Building from command line
- Starting VS (or the command line) as administrator

Comment: Have you tried restarting your PC? Also try to repair the .NET Framework and Visual Studio installation

Comment: Yup. I tried a full reinstall of Visual Studio 2015 and the .NET framework , but to no avail.

Comment: Try running VS as administrator

Comment: Also, are you building with Debug or Release config?

Comment: Running the environment as a administrator didn't solve the issue either. Most of the time I'm building the Debug configuration, but the error occurs on all configurations. Both debug and release, and for all platforms (x86, x64 and ARM).

Comment: As weird as it may sound, try updating your GPU drivers. Also try this: Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->Linker->Advanced->Randomize Base Address: No

Comment: Did you try to set owner of your project folder to you?

Comment: Do you have anything like what's mentioned [here](http://thomasmartinsen.com/2015/01/13/child-node-exited-prematurely-shutting-down/) going on wherein you're maybe porting something old over to UWP and forgot a handler that doesn't exist but is still in a template somewhere?

Comment: @ChrisW. That article pointed me in the right direction (see answer). Thank you so much.

Comment: Cool deal, glad you found a remedy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of [this article](http://thomasmartinsen.com/2015/01/13/child-node-exited-prematurely-shutting-down/) linked in Chris W.'s comment I was able to figure it out. In this case the error indicates an issue with one of the `ResourceDictionary` in the project.

It turns out one of the `ResourceDictionary` in my project contained a duplicate namespace declaration.

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MyApp.UAP.Base">

    <Style TargetType="local:TTBasePage"  xmlns:local="using:MyApp.UAP.Base"> <!-- This line caused  the error -->
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:TTBasePage">
                    <Border
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Removing this duplicate namespace declaration solved the build error.

According to the article it can also be caused by other `ResourceDictionary` related issues (invalid eventhandlers on your templates etc.).